# ASP.Net MVC - How to construct this button to call a function from a controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.Net and to be honest my teacher wasn't very helpfull.

I'm making a simple online store as a project and I'm trying to construct a "Buy" button that will add the product to the cart and redirect the user to their cart.

Here's the function I'm trying to call

```
        {
            Zamawiany Z = new Zamawiany();           // object that represents a product in a cart, the class Zamawiany is not a table in database
            Prod P = new Prod();
            P = ProductBuId(Convert.ToInt32(id));    //my own function to find this product by id
            Z.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            Z.Ilosc = ilosc;
            Z.Waga = Convert.ToInt32(P.Waga);
            Z.Cena = Convert.ToInt32(P.Cena);
            Koszyk.Instance.WKoszyku.Add(Z);        //class Koszyk is a singleton and contains a list of Zamawiany objects
            return ViewBasket();
        }
```

And here's the page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Prod</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nazwa)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nazwa)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cena)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cena)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Waga)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Waga)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Kategoria)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Kategoria)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Il_Dost)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Il_Dost)
        </dd>

    </dl>
    <div class="input-group">

        <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Il_Dost) id="Amound">
        //buttons are supposed to be here
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I tried this two ways

1. ```
   <input type="button" value="Kup" class="form-control" href="<%: Url.Action("DodajDoKoszyka", "ProdsController", new { id = Model.ID , ilosc = document.getElementById('Amound').value } ) %>">
   ```

The page loads but when i click the button nothing happens. I'm not beeing taken to the cart.

2.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Kup","DodajDoKoszyka", "ProdsController", new { id = Model.ID, ilosc = document.getElementById("Amound").value })
```

When trying to acces the page I get a compiler error

```
CS0103: The name 'document' does not exist in the current context
```

and it points to this line. I tried googling this error and I got sugestions to put `<text>` around the js code but when I do Visual Studio gives me `The name 'text' does not exist in the current context.`

What's the best way to construct this button?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix javascript into urls....

You could define a form, with an  and action pointing to your controller action, populate that with your value, then your form can post the value to your action. Alternatively set an onclick handler on the button, get the value with javascript then navigate to the action passing the parameter.

Also this won't work

```
max=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Il_Dost)
```

As DisplayFor will write a whole element, you probably want just max="@modelIl_Dost"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a form to post your data to server like so:

```
<form asp-controller="ProdsController" asp-action="DodajDoKoszyka" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="@Model.Il_Dost" name="Amound">
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ID" name="ModelId" />
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form should send post request to specified controller and method. Your method should accept two parameters, `ModelId` and `Amound`.